# grep STOP regex replacing -A option

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm looking/searching for a way to make grep stop when finding the "|_" specific string after having found
the search string.

for example, i want to print ONLY the lines starting 2 lines above "address-info:" and stopping at line "|_"
AND NOT print "irrelevant lines in between" which BTW could by anything

INPUT:

```
Nmap scan report for ::1.2.3.4
Host script results:
| address-info:
|   IPv4-compatible:
|_    IPv4 address: 1.2.3.4
...
irrelevant lines in between
irrelevant lines in between
irrelevant lines in between
...
Nmap scan report for ::ffff:1.2.3.4
Host script results:
| address-info:
|   IPv4-mapped:
|_    IPv4 address: 1.2.3.4
...
irrelevant lines in between
irrelevant lines in between
irrelevant lines in between
...
Nmap scan report for 2001:0:506:708:282a:3d75:fefd:fcfb
Host script results:
| address-info:
|   Teredo:
|     Server IPv4 address: 5.6.7.8
|     Client IPv4 address: 1.2.3.4
|_    UDP port: 49802
```

OUTPUT:

```
Nmap scan report for ::1.2.3.4
Host script results:
| address-info:
|   IPv4-compatible:
|_    IPv4 address: 1.2.3.4
Nmap scan report for ::ffff:1.2.3.4
Host script results:
| address-info:
|   IPv4-mapped:
|_    IPv4 address: 1.2.3.4
Nmap scan report for 2001:0:506:708:282a:3d75:fefd:fcfb
Host script results:
| address-info:
|   Teredo:
|     Server IPv4 address: 5.6.7.8
|     Client IPv4 address: 1.2.3.4
|_    UDP port: 49802
```

I'v read man grep and found -A -B -C options, it's OK for -B as I know in advance how many line before but for -A
I gave an arbituray high value ie: 99999 in

```
grep -A99999 -B2 address-info: INPUT.txt
```

and piping in awk to find "|_"

```
awk 'BEGIN {PAT=1} PAT == 1 {print $0} $1 ~ /^|_/ {PAT=0}
```

whole line:

```
grep -A99999 -B2 address-info: INPUT.txt | awk 'BEGIN {PAT=1} PAT == 1 {print $0} $1 ~ /^|_/ {PAT=0}'
```

this in unacceptable in production mode as is it not universal (NOT working in (very unlikly, but possible) cases where
the number of lines "address-info:" AND "|_" is more than 99999), CPU/MEM unefficiant and untidy.

I'd like to have a way WITHIN the grep command to acheive this,

any ideas ?

Comment: Have you considered using the "`grep` friendly" mode of `nmap`? For example `nmap -oG -`

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` directly with a range:

```
awk '/^Nmap scan report/;/^Host script results/,/\|_/' INPUT.txt
```

`grep` does not have any 'range' capabilities. But you can pipe the output of `grep address-info: -B2 -A 99999` to it.

Comment: OK, all 3 work, thx

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` to match the start of the lines you want (test if that doesn't match the other lines):

```
grep -E '^(Nmap scan report for|Host script results:|\|[ _])' INPUT.txt
```

Or `sed` and range pattern (similar to the [awk solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512413/332764))

```
sed -n '/^Nmap scan report for/,/^|_/p' INPUT.txt
```

- begin: `^Nmap scan report for`
- end: `^|_`

Comment: OK, all 3 work, thx